# Weird grep behavior with invalid UTF8 input

Tags: grep, tail

I need to monitor a log file which sometimes contains invalid UTF8 characters.

Like this:

```
shaozr@fedora utf8-cut (bear_from_3.1.18) $ tail -F a.txt
a我々はMozartが好きです。
a我々はBachも好きです。
a▒▒▒々はMozartが好きです。
a▒b々はMozartが好きです。
a我々はMoz▒rtが好きです。
a我々はMozartが好きです。
```

I can filter the content by 'pipe to grep' once :

```
shaozr@fedora utf8-cut (bear_from_3.1.18) $ tail -F a.txt | grep -a Mozart
a我々はMozartが好きです。
a▒▒▒々はMozartが好きです。
a▒b々はMozartが好きです。
a我々はMozartが好きです。
a▒▒▒々はMozartが好きです。
a▒b々はMozartが好きです。
```

But I try to  filter the content by 'pipe to grep' more than once,
I just get nothing.

```
shaozr@fedora utf8-cut (bear_from_3.1.18) $ tail -F a.txt | grep -a Mozart | grep -a Mozart
^C
shaozr@fedora utf8-cut (bear_from_3.1.18) $ tail -F a.txt | grep -a -v Bach | grep -a Mozart
^C
shaozr@fedora utf8-cut (bear_from_3.1.18) $
```

I have tried on grep v3.7 and v3.1, results are same.

And if I subsitue 'tail -F' with just 'cat',
above 'multi layer grep pips' works.

```
shaozr@fedora utf8-cut (bear_from_3.1.18) $ cat a.txt | grep -a -v Bach |  grep -a Mozart
a我々はMozartが好きです。
a▒▒▒々はMozartが好きです。
a▒b々はMozartが好きです。
a我々はMozartが好きです。
a▒▒▒々はMozartが好きです。
a▒b々はMozartが好きです。
a我々はMozartが好きです。
a▒▒▒々はMozartが好きです。
a▒b々はMozartが好きです。
```

What should I do to monitor&filter  text containing invalid utf8 char by 'pipe to grep' more than once?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this happen without the `-F` in `tail -F a.txt`?

Comment: Wow, if I subtitute 'tail' with just 'cat',  'multi grep pipes' works, what a suprise ^^

Comment: I revised my question,  'tail without -F' and 'cat' both work with 'multi grep pipe', interesting ^^

Comment: Thanks, that is it!